Is there a way to make gphoto2 faster?
I'm using gphoto2 on a Raspberry pi 4 to set the exposure and bracketing modes on my Nikon D500.  It seems anytime I execute any gphoto2 --set-confing.... or --get-config it takes nearly a full second.  So if a script has to set ISO, f-stop, shutter speed, turn bracketing on, set bracketing mode and set bracket count, that's like 5 seconds of waiting.  Also when I use --get-config to read settings it's just as slow I got that a little faster by executing gphoto2 --list-all-config and piping it into a c program I wrote to ignore most of the output and only show the settings I'm interested in.  I can share that code here if anyone would like to use it.
Taking photos takes way too long as well but now I just have it set the exposures and I use a remote shutter release to fire shot off at 10 frames a second.
FYI I'm trying to get as many shots during the total eclipse phase as possible and  need to shoot exposures covering about 20 stops.  My camera's bracketing function helps but 9 stops is the most it will do.  So I shoot 9 have gphoto2 change the exposure by 10 stops and shoot 9 more etc.
I read somewhere that the gphoto2 shell maintains connection with the camera and should be faster, but I can't type fast enough so I thought maybe I could pipe a file with a list of commands into the shell but it didn't work.
cat commandScript | gphoto2 --shell
It would be nice to be able to pass more than one --set-config to the command on the same line but it doesn't seem like that's possible either.

I'm also trying to set things up for the eclipse, but with a Nikon Z6ii.
You can send multiple commands at once with gphoto2:
gphoto2 --set-config shutterspeed2=1/250 --trigger-capture --trigger-capture --trigger-capture
The above (i.e., using several --trigger-captures at once and not downloading the images to my laptop) is the fastest way I've found, though there certainly might be something better. I can get several shots a second this way. I have a bash script that sets off commands at appropriate times.
My main issue is that the camera keeps resetting the number of shots in a bracket sequence to 3 and gphoto2 --get-config aebracketingcount tells me that it's readonly. Are you able to set the number of frames in the bracketing from gphoto2? I suppose this could be camera dependent.

The first thing you need to do is run gphoto2 --list-all-config and search in the output for bracketing.   On my camera I found that the bracketing options were all read only until bracketing was turned on, then they weren't read only.  I also found that not all of the bracketing options are listed with nice names.  To set the number of frames for bracketing I had to set-config d0c2=7 for 9 frame bracketing.  the choices it lists when you do get-config d0c2 don't tell you what the mode really is so it's best to set it up with the camera before connecting it with gphoto2 then list-all-config

I did know I could have several trigger capture commands on one line and that got me about 5 frames per second, but the camera will do 10 so I'm just using my remote to take the photos.  what I couldn't get to work was setting ISO, f-stop and shutter speed all on one line.  I'm doing 2 sets of 9 bracket shots and have to change all three settings for each set.  BTW I would do manual bracketing not AE, your built in light meter will be useless during the total eclipse.
